# ember: best way to reuse controller actions on mixins

Tags: ember.js

Example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ICoLOgO/4/edit

If I have a mixin that provides an action, with ember 1.0-rc.5 the action would be invoked without warnings. Upgrading to ember 1.0 final causes a deprecation warning to show:

```
Action handlers implemented directly on controllers are deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object
```

Is there a simpler way to expose individual actions in an action map without needing to use function.apply?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just put the common actions in the `actions` hash on the mixin, and Ember took care of properly merging the actions hashes with any controllers that extend the mixin.

```
App.PaginatedListController = Ember.Mixin.create({
  queryParams: ['page'],
  page: 0,

  actions: {
    nextPage: function() {
      this.incrementProperty('page');
    },

    previousPage: function() {
      this.decrementProperty('page');
    },
  }
});

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(App.PaginatedListController, {
  actions: {
    // controller specific actions here
  }
});
```